# How to make the Reset password link to expiry in SAP CDC

Tags: gigya

I am working on email template in SAP CDC. There is a template which is for password reset. In that I have a reset password link which is for resetting the password. Now I need to expire that link after 30 minutes when user clicking on that link.

How to add expire time in SAP CDC email template?

[image: SAP CDC email templates]

[image: reset password link]

$pwResetLink - this is the keyword that parsing for password reset link. I need to add expire time.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify link expiration time In reset password mail, you need to got to specific API Key, under Identity -> Security -> Authentication you should see below:

[image]